# Spring Boot app no able to connect to DynamoDB and SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs

I'm creating a Spring Boot project that will consume messages from an AWS SQS queue and then interact with DynamoDB, I'm trying to create the @Configuration class in order to provide the AmazonDynamoDB and AmazonSQSAsync beans:

**Configuration** class:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.config.EnableDynamoDBRepositories;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

@Configuration
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(basePackages = "org.myapp.repository")
public class AWSConfigdelete {
    @Value("${myapp.aws.region.static}")
    private String region;

    @Value("${myapp.aws.credentials.access-key}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${myapp.aws.credentials.secret-key}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Value("${myapp.aws.dynamodb-endpoint}")
    private String dynamoDBEndpoint;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync() {

        BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicAWSCredentials))
                .withRegion(region)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)))
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(dynamoDBEndpoint, region))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate() {
        return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSQSAsync());
    }
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }
}
```

The **application.yml** file

```
cloud:
  aws:
    stack:
      auto: false
    region:
      static: us-east-1
      auto: false
    credentials:
      access-key: myacccesskey
      secret-key: mysecretkey

server:
  port: 8070

myapp:
  aws:
    region:
      static: us-east-1
    credentials:
      access-key: myacccesskey
      secret-key: mysecretkey
    dynamodb-endpoint: https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    queue1:
      sqs:
        queue:
          url: https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/123456789/my-queue-1
    queue2:
      sqs:
        queue:
          url: https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/123456789/my-queue-2

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

My **pom.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>processor</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myapp-processor</name>
    <description>Processor</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.486</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I was able to access and interact with DynamoDB, but since I added the SQS configuration and dependencies I'm not able to connect to any of the AWS services, and always getting this error:

> com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils      : Unable to retrieve the
> requested metadata (/latest/meta-data/instance-id). Failed to connect
> to service endpoint:
>
> com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service
> endpoint:  ..... Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Host is down
> (connect failed)

**Thanks for your hints and/or recommendations.**

Answer (score 0):

You are using AWS SDK for Java V1, which is not best practice or [recommended](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main#isolated-code-examples). Try using **AWS SDK for Java V2**. Using this SDK Version in a Spring Boot app works fine.

We have an example here that uses ***AWS SDK for Java V2*** within a Spring Boot app that uses Amazon DynamoDB and returns JSON data that a React app displays.

[Creating a Spring Boot application that queries Amazon DynamoDB data](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_dynamodb_web_app)